# How to schedule a cron script to run every hour? rather than every time someone visits the site?

Tags: wordpress, cron

My resources are being reached and maxed out. I got recommended I run a cron job every hour. My question is, what cron job script do I enter?

I disabled **DISABLE_WP_CRON** and I am expecting my website to not use many resources.

I am using [Hostinger](https://www.hostinger.com/) web hosting.

Comment: Defining a cron job to run once an hour is the easy part: `0 * 0 0 0 command...`. What you need to figure out is how to set up a cron job to run on your web host (and I have no idea how to do that).

Answer (score 0):

To be clear as mud, you should *enable* DISABLE_WP_CRON like this:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

That way it won't rely on someone hitting the site to run the WP cron jobs.

IIRC here is the cron job you need on the server:

```
0 * * * wget -q -O - https://DOMAINNAME.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Basically you're telling the server cron job to, every hour, go hit that wp-cron.php file which will trigger the WP cron jobs.

You'll have to look up something more specific from Hostinger to figure out *where* to put that command. Typically you SSH into your server, run `crontab -e`, and add the command as another line in that file. But depending on the host they might not let you do that, or they have something like cPanel that gives you an alternate method of entering cron commands.

If you are really in a pinch like "my host does not let me add cron jobs on the server at all" then you can use a ping service like https://uptimerobot.com/. Give that your cron URL (https://DOMAINNAME.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron) and it will trigger your WP crons that way.